# How to handle old user input in a newly disabled field

Tags: forms

I have a form where there is a input thats only enabled with certain other settings. However there is a case where a user enters something in that conitional field, and then changes the other setting such that the conitional field is now disabled.

From this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZBSIb.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

To this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjzE9P.png)</sup>

Whats the proper way to handle this situation? Leave the user input displayed (and ignore it)? Clear it out every time you toggle the conditional field?

Comment: When you say "conditional field," are you saying that the field might or might not be enabled based on other factors or earlier input, or simply that the user can enable or disable it as they see fit?

Comment: Enabled based on earlier inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess my main question is this: does the value in the optional field still register once the field is disabled? **If they enter a value before it is disabled, and that value still is respected/used by the system even AFTER it is disabled, then the value should remain visible in the disabled field. If not, and that field is simply disregarded when disabled, I would suggest removing any content from the disabled field.**